# Best method for showing/hiding form elements based on other form input and validation?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am in the process of revamping a website using ASP.NET C# web forms. I have very little experience on the matter, and wondered. Is there best practice for showing or hiding form elements based on what is selected on other elements in the form in ASP.NET using c#? For example, if I select option 1 from a drop down list, then an additional text box appears. Right now I am using jQuery to accomplish this. Which leads me to my second question as I am not sure how I will validate. Is there a best/preferred practice for validating form fields in ASP.NET? I have seen validation using knockout.js, ASP:RequiredValidation control, etc, but would like to know general consensus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best you can use are the native ASP validators, as they validate both on client and server side.

For what you describe, you might be in a certain escenario where the requiredFieldValidation and the others validators won't be enough, as you have to use your own complex logic for validation.

In this case, and just to be sure, i would validate both on the server side with [CustomFieldValidators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5db6z8k(v=vs.140).aspx) and client side using jQuery as you're already doing.

For simple validations like, a field that cannot be empty or a regular expression matching validation the other native asp validators do the trick.

Note that this is for security purposes only, the advantage of this validators is that they validate both on client and server side, if you only validate on client side, and rely on that for you application's security, it might be exposed if someone disables JavaScript in the browser to bypass client-side validation.